# "clocksource tsc unstable" shown when the linux kernel boots up

Tags: linux, kernel

I am booting up a linux kernel using a full system simulator, and I'd like to run my benchmark on the booted system. However, when it boots up, it shows me this message: "clocksource tsc unstable" and occasionally it hangs in the beggining. However, sometimes it lets me run my benchmark and then probably it hangs in the middle since the application never finishes and seems it's stuck there. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that, kernel didn't manage to calculate tsc (Time Stamp Counter) value properly i.e value is stale. This usually happens with VM. The way to avoid this is to - use predefined lpj (loops per jiffy) as kernel parameter (lpj=). Try it, hope issue will be fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does that mean that I need to compile the kernel and build a new one?

Comment: Not at all. That means you need to pass it when you pick an entry from grub, when grub menu comes up - press 'e' to edit grub menu. Then, at the line starts with 'kernel ...', add lpj= at the end of this line. Find out appropriate value for it, by experimenting with different values.